# need help with jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got code like that:

```
<ul class="gallery_demo_unstyled">
    <li class="active"><img src='001.jpg' /></li> 
    <li><img src='002.jpg' /></li> 
    <li><img src='003.jpg' /></li> 
    <li><img src='004.jpg' /></li> 
    <li><img src='005.jpg' /></li> 
    <li><img src='006.jpg' /></li> 
</ul> 

<div class="Paginator"> 
    <a href="../2/" class="Prev">&lt;&lt;</a> 
    <a href="../1/">1</a> 
    <a href="../2/">2</a> 
    <span class="this-page">3</span> 
    <a href="../4/">4</a> 
    <a href="../5/">5</a> 
    <a href="../4/" class="Next">&gt;&gt;</a> 
</div> 

<div class="Albums"><div class="AlbumsMenu">
<p><b>ALBUMS</b></p>
    <p><a href="../../blackandwhite/1/" >blackandwhite</a></p>
    <p><a href="../../color/1/" class='this-page'>>>color</a></p>
    <p><a href="../../film/1/" >film</a></p>
    <p><a href="../../digital/1/" >digital</a></p>
    <p><a href="../../portraits/1/" >portraits</a></p>
</div></div>
```

...and some JavaScript/jQuery allowing to cycle through the images (the very top li elements) going back to the first image after the last one:

```
$$.nextSelector = function(selector) {
return $(selector).is(':last-child') ?
       $(selector).siblings(':first-child') :
       $(selector).next();

};
```

Current page is always 'this-page' class (span or p in my case, but I could change that if necessary).

**The question**: what should I change in my code to make it go after the last image to the next page instead of cycling through the page over and over again, and after the last page to the next album? And to the first image on the first page of the first album after the last-last-last (or just stop there — don't really care)?

Comment: how are you updating the list of images, and the pages inside a gallery? is there an ajax request that updates `ul. gallery_demo_unstyled` when a new page is opened, and `div.AlbumsMenu` when a new album is opened?

Comment: @anurag: it's the <a href'http://lomoportfolio.com/trunk/jquery.galleria.js'>galleria.js</a> script. I'm generating html with list of images, page numbers and albums links via django - one html per album-page, and inside one page [li class="active"] is for one image is dynamically changed by clicking on a large image. Demo is here: http://lomoportfolio.com/strangers.html for example, but now it's cycling within one page. I want it to go to the next page, then next album after the last picture on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this:

```
function nextImage()
{
    var li = $('#gallery_demo_unstyled li.active');

    if (li.is(':last-child')) {
        nextPage();
    } else {
        li.removeClass('active');
        li.next().addClass('active');
    }
}

function nextPage()
{
    var next = $('div.Paginator a.Next');

    if (next.length == 0) {
        nextAlbum();
    } else {
        window.location = next.attr('href');
    }
}

function nextAlbum()
{
    var this_album = $('div.AlbumsMenu p a.this-name');
    var p = this_album.parent();

    if (p.next().length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    window.location = p.next().children('a').attr('href');
}
```

Comment: To make it working it'll need to return selector instead of actually doing all the magic. Will think about how to modify it. But thank you!